How to dynamically set the agent's layout based on customized parameters in AnyLogic?
I have created an airport agent in AnyLogic to simulate pedestrian and airplane movements inside an airport. Now I want to differentiate between large and small airports based on a custom flag variable. Both airports are different in terms of number of security check machines, number of check-in counters and spatial layout. How can I dynamically generate two types of airports, large and small, by passing different values of the flag variable during agent creation?
I've currently implemented the repositioning of security machines, check-in counters, guide text and decorations such as flower pots and sofas by using the setPos() function. Although I can't call the relevant function on wall to adjust the position of the wall, I solved the problem by setting the wall using polyline.
However, I am not able to implement position adjustment for markup elements like TargetLine, RectangularNode using setPos() function, I get error message showing “java.lang.RuntimeException: root: node (RectangularNode) : Markup element is already initialized and cannot be modified. Please use constructor without arguments, perform setup and finally call initialize() function.”
I tried constructing the instance using the constructor without arguments first, and then adjusting the position of the corresponding elements in it. However, since I created an empty instance, the TargetLine and RectangularNode that I drew in the graphical editor have not been initialized yet, so I need to redefine these elements before I can reposition them. But the elements I defined in the code can't be bound to the components of the logic flow I drew in the graphical editor (e.g. pedSource and pedWait). Also, since the program initializes all the elements in the layout in the graphical editor afterwards, the positional changes I make are not reflected in the final layout.
Currently I can only achieve the scalability I want by setting up two sets of TargetLine and RectangularNode elements to correspond to the two types of airports, large and small, and then setting up the corresponding elements to be visible according to the flag variable?
Thanks in advance for your help!

See the help: https://anylogic.help/markup/create-network-by-code-mhl.html#create-network-by-code
Also, pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse 1000s of SOF users that do not know what AnyLogic is (but check for your other tags)

@Benjamin. Thank you very much for the prompt answer! It helps a lot.
